# How to delete a column from parent table and propagate this to all child tables

Tags: postgresql

Can someone help me with this? I have a set of tables that are inherited from a single parent table (now all these tables are containing data).

I need to drop a particular column from the parent table and the same column from all inherited tables should be dropped automatically. Is this possible?

When I tried this, only the parent table column was dropped. I tried cascade option also in the alter table, but no result.

I am using postgreSql 8.3

Answer (score 3):

I have just come across this same issue with Postgres 9.3.
The problem only appears to exist in the following scenarios:

1)

```
create table parent_table(a int);
create table child_table(a int) inherits (parent_table);
```

2)

```
create table parent_table(a int);
create table child_table(a int);
alter table child_table INHERIT parent_table;
```

Scenario 2) is more likely than 1), since in 1) you could instead do:

```
create table parent_table(a int);
create table child_table() inherits (parent_table);
```

and get the same columns in both tables.

In scenario 2) however, child_table must have all of parent_table's columns and their constraints. According to the Postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html):

> INHERIT parent_table
>
> This form adds the target table as a new child of the specified parent table. Subsequently, queries against the parent will include records of the target table. To be added as a child, the target table must already contain all the same columns as the parent (it could have additional columns, too). The columns must have matching data types, and if they have NOT NULL constraints in the parent then they must also have NOT NULL constraints in the child.
>
> There must also be matching child-table constraints for all CHECK constraints of the parent. Currently UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, and FOREIGN KEY constraints are not considered, but this might change in the future.

The result of this is that if you have added inheritance to a table after the fact, and then drop a column in the parent table, that column WILL NOT be dropped from the child table, even if you use DROP CASCADE.

Comment: +1 for your answer... so whats the solution for that? I mean If i want to drop the column from the parent table, is there anyway for automatically drop same column from from child table?? (for scenario 2)

Comment: I'm afraid I think the answer is no, unless your child table was created as

`create table child_table() inherits (parent_table);`

Answer (score 1):

When we add column through looping through all inherited tables, then removing column from main table doesn't remove from every inherited tables, it will remove from every inherited tables, only when we add column by adding it to main table. Also no 'CASCADE; is required.
(Checked with PostgreSQl)

```
ALTER TABLE 'Table_Name' ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS 'Col_Name' 'type'
ALTER TABLE 'Table_Name' DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS 'Col_Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

When a column is dropped in a parent table, it should get dropped in inherited tables as well.
The [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-inherit.html) says:

> ALTER TABLE will propagate any changes in column data definitions and
>   check constraints down the inheritance hierarchy. Again, dropping
>   columns or constraints on parent tables is only possible when using
>   the CASCADE option. ALTER TABLE follows the same rules for duplicate
>   column merging and rejection that apply during CREATE TABLE.

Try this:

```
create table parent_table(a int, b int);
create table child_table(c int) inherits (parent_table);
```

Result:

```
# \d child_table 
  Table "public.child_table"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 a      | integer | 
 b      | integer | 
 c      | integer | 
Inherits: parent_table
```

Now let's drop a column in `parent_table`:

```
alter table parent_table drop column a cascade;
```

Result:

```
\d child_table 
  Table "public.child_table"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 b      | integer | 
 c      | integer | 
Inherits: parent_table
```

The DROP COLUMN has been propagated to the child table as expected.

If you get different results with your tables definition, you should include these definitions in the question as well as the drop SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am getting this result when I create new tables and trying the above steps. But the issue is happening in a database where all child tables are containing good amount of data. Can this cause a problem?

Comment: I have created a fresh DB and inserted some data into these tables and tried dropping the parent column. It is working fine and all child tables are reflected with this change. So I think this is not to do with data. Could there be any other reasons?

Comment: Daniel... Sorry but not working.... did these steps. (  create table manan (id integer, name text); insert into manan values (1,'a'),(2,'b'); create table manan1 as select * from manan; alter table manan1 INHERIT manan; alter table manan drop column name cascade; \d manan; \d manan1; ) ...got  that....for sceanario2 (@Araphel's post) it is not working....

Comment: Inheritance added after the fact with `ALTER TABLE` was not mentioned in the question or in my answer. In fact I wasn't ever aware this was possible when I wrote this. For a good answer, please ask a new question specifically about ALTER TABLE...INHERIT followed by DROP COLUMN instead of piggybacking on this bad question.